# Remove entry from map without iterating

Tags: java, dictionary

How do I remove entry from **Java** `Map` without using iteration using value or key. Basically in my map, I am using `containsKey()` then `map.remove()` to remove it.

Comment: Haven't you just answered your own question..?

Comment: @hexacyanide without using iterator. I am not able to

Comment: @user1610812 You still just answered your own question. Use remove without the iterator as the answers here show.

Comment: 5 duplicate answers so far

Answer (score 21):

You remove an entry from a map by using the key of the element that you wish to remove.

```
map.remove("aKey");
```

If you don't know the key of the element you must iterate to obtain it such as this:

```
public static <T, E> Set<T> getKeysByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {
     Set<T> keys = new HashSet<T>();
     for (Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {
         if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
             keys.add(entry.getKey());
         }
     }
     return keys;
}
```

This will return all the keys that were found on the map.

Comment: You need not iterate. `remove()` will use equals internally already.

Comment: @hexafraction in a List you have remove(Object o) but that's not the case for Map. For Map you only have remove(Object key), so if you don't know the key you have to find it first.

Comment: No matter if generic or not, the map always accepts an Object to remove. See [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) here.

Comment: @hexafraction my bad, but still it is the key, not the object you wish to remove.

Answer (score 12):

```
Map<Integer, String> abcMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
abcMap.put(1,"A");
abcMap.put(2,"B");
abcMap.put(3,"C");

/// now for remove item
abcMap.remove(1);
// this will remove "A" from abcMap..
```

Answer (score 10):

In most cases you can remove entry (key-value pair) from a map using `Map.remove(key)` method. There will be no iteration over the map. You don't need to use `Map.containsKey(key)` before the `Map.remove(key)` because `Map.remove` already does it. It returns either a previous associated value with `key` or `null` if there was no mapping for the `key`.

But you can't do the same thing using a value only (without key). The only option is to iterate via map and find entry (or entries) with that value.

Java 5-7:

```
for (Iterator<MyValue> it = map.values.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    if(it.next().equals(myValue)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Java 8:

```
map.values().removeIf(v -> v.equals(myValue));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Map#remove(Object key)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29):

> ```
> public V remove(Object key)
> ```
>
> Removes the mapping for this key from this map if it is present (optional operation). More formally, if this map contains a mapping from key k to value v such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, that mapping is removed. (The map can contain at most one such mapping.)
>
> Returns the value to which the map previously associated the key, or null if the map contained no mapping for this key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with the specified key if the implementation supports null values.) The map will not contain a mapping for the specified key once the call returns.

Basically you can call remove, even if the key does not exist. It will silently fail in that case(returning null). The object need not be identical or the same, if `yourKey.equals(key)` is true for the key you want to remove.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Object remove(Object key)
```

`remove` method in `Map`.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29):

Removes the mapping for this key from this map if it is present (optional operation). More formally, if this map contains a mapping from key k to value v such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)),` that mapping is removed. (The map can contain at most one such mapping.)

Returns the value to which the map previously associated the key, or `null` if the map contained no mapping for this key. (A `null` return can also indicate that the map previously associated `null` with the specified key if the implementation supports `null` values.) The map will not contain a mapping for the specified key once the call returns.

**Parameters:**

key - key whose mapping is to be removed from the map.

**Returns**:

Previous value associated with specified key, or `null` if there was no mapping for key.

**Example:**

```
Map<Integer, String> map=new HashMap<>();
    map.put(20, "stackOverflow");
    System.out.println(map.remove(20));
```

This code will print `"stackOverflow"` i.e. Previous value associated with specified key. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems nobody here actually answered OP's question. They were asking how, without using an iterator, to remove an entry **"using value or key"**. Of course `remove(key)` works if you have the key, but not if you are searching for a *value*.

[Alfredo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438842/554518) was closest, in that it searches the value side of the `Map`, but it uses an iterator.

Here's a solution using Java 8's `Stream` API; no iterators:

```
Map<K, V> newMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> !entry.getKey().equals(searchValue))
    .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().equals(searchValue))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

(Substitute `K` and `V` for your key and value types.)

Comment: You suggest to recreate the whole map. That's extremely inefficient idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Map`'s `remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), which takes a key as an argument.  You don't need the original object; you just need an object that compares equal to the existing key in the map with `equals`, and produces the same `hashCode` as the existing key in the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Constant.mapCustomer.remove("s");
     Map<String, String> mapCustomer=new HashMap<String, String> ();;
     mapCustomer.put("s","ss");
    System.out.println(mapCustomer.get("s"));
    mapCustomer.remove("s");
    System.out.println(mapCustomer.get("s"));
}
```