# How to remove items from a HashMap via keyboard input?

Tags: java, hashmap

My problem is the `deleteEntry` method (second last method). I want to be able to type in an Integer via Scanner which position shall be deleted from the HashMap. So if I have 5 Objects in the HashMap and type in a 3 in the remove method it should remove the third entry. How can I do this?

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShoppingList
{
   private HashMap<String, Integer> list;
   private Scanner sc;
   private int input;
   private String article;
   private int number;
   private int index;
   private int value;

    public ShoppingList()
    {
       list = new HashMap<>();
       sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       article = null;
       number = 1;
    }


    public void menue(){
        do{
            System.out.println("___________________________________________________");
            System.out.println("1. Add Entry");
            System.out.println("2. Show List");
            System.out.println("3. Delete Entry");
            System.out.println("4. Delete List");            
            System.out.println("0. Exit");
            System.out.println("___________________________________________________");

            input = sc.nextInt();

            switch (input){
                case 1:
                addEntry(); break;   
                case 2:
                showList(); break;        
                case 3:
                deleteEntry(); break;                 
                case 4:
                deleteList(); break;                                
                default:
                System.out.println("Exit"); break;   
            }
        }
            while (input != 0);
    }

    public void addEntry(){

           System.out.println("Add Entry: "); 
           article = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Number: ");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            list.put(article, number);      
      }

    public void showList(){
      Iterator <String> it = list.keySet().iterator();
      for (String key : list.keySet()){
       System.out.println(key + ": " + list.get(key));
      }
    }

    public void deleteEntry(){
     System.out.println("Number of item you want to remove:");

     index = sc.nextInt();
     index = index--;
     value = list.get(index);
     list.remove(value);
    }    

    public void deleteList(){
      list.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: In maps there are no positions. If you want to work with positions, use lists.

Comment: What kind of List would you recommend if I want to store an Item and a number of items in there together?

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote. This seems like a valid and clear Question to me.

Comment: To *What kind of List would you recommend*: For this purpose is really doesn't matter. E.g. you can take ArrayList or LinkedList.

Comment: Similar: [*Remove entry from map without iterating*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19438785/642706)

Answer (score 0):

## `Map` is not ordered

A `Map` implementation does not have an order. You are asking to retrieve a map entry by ordinal number such as third or fifth. That makes no sense in the context of a map. There is **no such thing as “the third entry”** in a `Map`. You can do so with a `List` but not a `Map`.

Some maps do have the concept of iteration order of keys. Most implementations bundled with Java 11 do not support this, but a few do.

- A couple of implantations implement the [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface, and its predecessor, the `SortedMap` interface. Both iterate by the natural-ordering of the keys, or by a `Compatator` you pass.

  - `TreeMap`
  - `ConcurrentSkipListMap`
- `LinkedHashMap` iterates entries in the order in which they were originally inserted.
- `EnumMap` iterates entries in the order in which the key was defined in its class, in its `Enum` subclass.

But none of these support access by ordinal number or index. You can get the first or last entry. For other positions between first/lowest and last/highest, you must iterate.

Here is a table highlighting the characteristics of the 10 implementations of `Map` bundled with Java 11. Notice the *iteration order* column.

[image]

## Workaround: `Map::keySet` > `List` > `Collections.sort` > `List::get` > `Map::get`

To accomplish your goal, perhaps you could call `keySet` to get a `Set` of the key objects. Then make a list of those in some order that you like. Present that list in your user interface. When user asks for the fifth item, retrieve by index (5-1) from the list to have a key in hand. Then go to your map and call `get` for the value stored for that particular key.

Something like this example code.

```
Map < Person, String > personToProjectMap = new HashMap <>( 5 );
personToProjectMap.put( new Person( "Carol" , "Connelly" ) , "Inventory Report" );
personToProjectMap.put( new Person( "Alice" , "Anderson" ) , "Sales Report" );
personToProjectMap.put( new Person( "Bob" , "Barker" ) , "Staff Report" );
personToProjectMap.put( new Person( "Edith" , "Enders" ) , "Marketing Report" );
personToProjectMap.put( new Person( "David" , "Dount" ) , "Investment Report" );

System.out.println( "DEBUG map size: " + personToProjectMap.size() );
System.out.println( "DEBUG personToProjectMap.toString() = " + personToProjectMap );

Set < Person > persons = personToProjectMap.keySet();
List < Person > personsList = new ArrayList <>( persons );  // Populate a `List` by feeding the items from our `Set`.
Collections.sort(       // Use the `Collections` utility class to sort our `List` by first name of each person used as a key in our map.
        personsList ,
        Comparator.comparing( ( Person person ) -> person.getGivenName() )
);

System.out.println( "DEBUG personsList.toString() = " + personsList );

// Present this list to the user in user-interface.
System.out.println( "Enter the number of the entry to remove." );
int nthPerson = 0;
for ( Person person : personsList )
{
    nthPerson++;
    System.out.println( "№ " + nthPerson + " " + person.getGivenName() + " ➙ " + personToProjectMap.get( person ) );
}
// …
int input = 3;   // … user enters 3
int index = ( input - 1 );
Person personPicked = personsList.get( index ); // Annoying zero-based counting for index.
personToProjectMap.remove( personPicked ); // Remove entry for the person picked by user.

System.out.println( "DEBUG map size: " + personToProjectMap.size() );
System.out.println( "DEBUG Result of deleting item from map:" );
System.out.println( personToProjectMap.toString() );
```

When run.

> DEBUG map size: 5
>
> DEBUG personToProjectMap.toString() = {Person{ givenName='Bob' | surname='Barker' }=Staff Report, Person{ givenName='Edith' | surname='Enders' }=Marketing Report, Person{ givenName='Carol' | surname='Connelly' }=Inventory Report, Person{ givenName='Alice' | surname='Anderson' }=Sales Report, Person{ givenName='David' | surname='Dount' }=Investment Report}
>
> DEBUG personsList.toString() = [Person{ givenName='Alice' | surname='Anderson' }, Person{ givenName='Bob' | surname='Barker' }, Person{ givenName='Carol' | surname='Connelly' }, Person{ givenName='David' | surname='Dount' }, Person{ givenName='Edith' | surname='Enders' }]
>
> Enter the number of the entry to remove.
>
> № 1 Alice ➙ Sales Report
>
> № 2 Bob ➙ Staff Report
>
> № 3 Carol ➙ Inventory Report
>
> № 4 David ➙ Investment Report
>
> № 5 Edith ➙ Marketing Report
>
> DEBUG map size: 4
>
> DEBUG Result of deleting item from map:
>
> {Person{ givenName='Bob' | surname='Barker' }=Staff Report, Person{ givenName='Edith' | surname='Enders' }=Marketing Report, Person{ givenName='Alice' | surname='Anderson' }=Sales Report, Person{ givenName='David' | surname='Dount' }=Investment Report}

Comment: Also, `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: @Basil Bourque: This answer is formally correct. But for somebody who is struggling to input a few characters (like author) this is really overkill :)

Comment: @mentallurg Well, as my Answer explains, there is no simple solution as `Map` does not offer access by ordinal number. Nevertheless, your Comment prompted me to go ahead and write some code to implement my suggestion at the end. Thank you for your input. Bonus for me: I got to discover `Comparator.comparing`.

Answer (score 0):

Each item in your shopping list is not just a product name, but also a quantity of that product. Someday (hypothetically) you might add other properties to each list item, like a maximum allowable price, or a sale price where you'd stock up on that product.

So, create a specialized type to represent the list items. You are trying to use a map entry for this purpose, but in an object-oriented language, you have much more powerful options.

Keep your items in a list, since order is important.

```
class ShoppingItem {
  private final String name;
  private final int quantity;
  ShoppingItem(String name, int quantity) {
    this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    if (quantity < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }
  String getName() { return name; }
  int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
}
```

Modify your current class to work with a `List<ShoppingItem>`:

```
public class ShoppingList {

  private List<ShoppingItem> list = new LinkedList<>();

  public void addEntry(){
    System.out.println("Add Entry: "); 
    String article = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Number: ");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    list.add(new ShoppingItem(article, number);
  }

  public void deleteEntry(){
    System.out.println("Number of item you want to remove:");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    list.remove(number - 1);
  }

  public void showList(){
    for (ShoppingItem item : list) {
      System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", item.getName(), item.getQuantity());
    }
  }

  ... /* Etc. */
```

Note also that most of your class variables would be better as *local* variables, since the values assigned to them are only meaningful during the scope of a method.