# Deleting items the Lists contained within a HashMap

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `Hashmap<Long, List<Foo>> myMap`. I want to remove an item from any `List<Foo>` where the `Foo.key` equals *value* assign to the `key` variable.

Is there a good way to do this with streams? I am using the following code to delete the item, which doesn't seem the best to me:

```
for (List<Foo> l : myMap.values()) {
   for (Foo f : l) {
      if (f.getKey().equals(key)) {
         l.remove(f);
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove entry from map without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438785/remove-entry-from-map-without-iterating)

Comment: Your code only removes the first matching item from each list.  Was that intentional?  Or did you intend to remove all matching items from each list?

Answer (score 2):

Probably there are multiple ways to do this. Here is one:

```
myMap.values().forEach(list->list.removeIf(foo -> Objects.equals(foo.getKey(), key)));
```

The idea is to go over each list in the map and remove the elements that have the key you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is actually the most suitable tool for this task.

Since you need to modify the contents of the map, it means that you need a stream that will cause side effects. And that is discouraged by the [documentation of the Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

But you can enhance your code by using `removeIf()` method added to the `Collection` interface with **Java-8**.

```
public static void removeFooWithKey(Map<Long, List<Foo>> myMap, 
                                    String key) {
    
    for (List<Foo> foos : myMap.values()) {
        foos.removeIf(foo -> foo.getKey().equals(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```java
myMap.values().forEach(list -> list.removeIf(foo -> foo.getKey().equals(key)))
```

But [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate. It does not equal to your initial code. Probably if your collection consists of unique keys and you need to remove only one object `removeIf` will do a little overhead and compare all elements of colections.

**Solution 1. Remove by first matched index**

```java
myMap.values().forEach(list -> IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(index -> key.equals(list.get(index).getKey())).findFirst().ifPresent(list::remove))
```

**Solution 2. Own removeFirstIf method**

```java
myMap.values().forEach(list -> StreamUtils.removeFirst(list, foo -> key.equals(foo.getKey())));

public class StreamUtils {
    private StreamUtils() {

    }
    public static <T> T removeFirstIf(Iterable<? extends T> collection, Predicate<? super T> condition) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(collection);
        Objects.requireNonNull(condition);

        T value;

        final Iterator<? extends T> iterator = collection.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            value = iterator.next();
            if (condition.test(value)) {
                iterator.remove();
                return value;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Solution 3. Change your structure to Map<Long, Map<String, Foo>>**
*Assumption*: probably if your List consists of unique keys then you can change your structure from `Map<Long, List<Foo>>` to `Map<Long, Map<String, Foo>>`
Removing elements by `Key` will be simple and fast:

```java
Map<Long, Map<String, Foo>> myMapOfMaps = new HashMap<>();
myMapOfMaps.values().forEach(map -> map.remove(key));
```